# Does MongoDB maintain index statistics (data distribution for index key column)?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql

SQL Server makes use of index statistics in order to decide whether to make use of index or to perform direct table scan based on the selectivity of the where criteria. Statistics helps query optimizer to choose table scan over index seek/scan when the selectivity is very low.

Does MongoDB maintain index statistics the way SQL maintains? Does the performance suffer in MongoDB when the selectivity of the find criteria is very low? If yes, is there a way to deal with such queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the current version of MongoDB (2.4), statistics about each index key are not kept.

MongoDB query optimizer has a different approach to selecting which index to use (or whether to do a collection scan).  The first time you run a particular query, if there are several indexes that *could* be used for the query, the query engine tries all of them in parallel and the one that finishes first wins (the others get killed off) - now this is a simplification but in a nutshell that's how a query plan is selected for the next X queries (query plans are periodically re-evaluated at various points).

You can read more about this [in MongoDB documentation of indexes.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#query-optimization)

Comment: My question is index vs collection scan using index statistics based on selectivity. Suppose, there is just one secondary index on some field. Does MongoDB always makes use of the secondary index when the find criteria contains a single criteria on the index key field irrespective of the selectivity?

Comment: @AnandPatel Yes, well I have never seen it not to. It will effect how effective the index is but it will still use the index

Comment: same thing- at the same time a collection scan is also done - if it were to perform better than index scan then it's eligible to be selected as the "winning" plan.  Normally, if there is an "eligible" index it's much more likely that it will win over collection scan, unless the collection is really small and in RAM (indexes will be in RAM almost always).

Comment: a case to imagine is this: index on "sex" - it's very poor because a single value only narrows your documents to about half of them.  But that's still eliminating half the collection plus when scanning the actual documents if you get there via an index they just get streamed to the client and don't need to be examined to find that field and see if it matches.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky - to your previous comment - isn't it inefficient to actually run through all possible plans - collection scan and all applicable indexes and then the one that finishes first wins. Does it behave in the same manner in a true multi-user environment when many queries are pouring in at the same time? The above may be a different SO question.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: I have got the answer from the MongoDB link that you provided. "The MongoDB query optimizer processes queries and chooses the most efficient query plan for a query given the available indexes. The query system then uses this query plan each time the query runs. The query optimizer occasionally reevaluates query plans as the content of the collection changes to ensure optimal query plans"